# Unit of calculated area for polygons using raster package area function

Tags: r, polygon, raster, projection

I am trying to calculate the area (square km or miles) of the intersection of counties and watersheds in R using the raster package and the area function.
My code looks like this so far:

```
counties <- readOGR('C:\\Shapefiles\\tl_2017_us_county\\tl_2017_us_county.shp')
counties <- spTransform(counties, CRS("+init=epsg:3455"))

huc2_10 <- readOGR('C:\\Shapefiles\\WBD_10_HU2_Shape\\Shape\\WBDHU6.shp')
huc2_10 <- spTransform(huc2_10, CRS("+init=epsg:3455"))
```

I then intersect the two shapefiles:

```
pi <- raster::intersect(huc2_10, counties)
```

The units of this projection are normally in meters (I believe), as it is a NAD83 projection for southern South Dakota, so the area function should calculate area in square meters.  I am attempting to calculate the area (in square miles) of each polygon that is formed as a result of this intersection using the area function.

```
pi$area <- area(pi)/2.589988e6
```

However, the proj4string looks like this:

```
+init=epsg:3455 +proj=lcc +lat_1=44.4 +lat_2=42.83333333333334 +lat_0=42.33333333333334 +lon_0=-100.3333333333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

According to this, the units are "us-ft".  So, does the area function output areas for each polygon in square feet because of this?  This seems to make sense, but I would like to confirm this, changing my code to:

```
pi$area <- area(pi)/5280**2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The manual confirms what you expect:

```
?raster::area
```

> If x is a SpatialPolygons* object: area if each spatial object in squared meters if the CRS is longitude/latitude, or in squared map units (typically meter)

If your map units are feet, the area will be in square feet.